# How can I format `stat` date format to work with git-log?

Tags: git, bash, deployment, sh, stat

I want to use this command in a shell script to get all the commits since my last deploy:

`git log --since --after={1.day.ago} --format="%h% B"`

So I was thinking of using `stat` on the executable to get the date of the last build and passing it to this command.

However,

1. **I don't know how git wants the date formatted?** *(all I've found is the 1.day.ago style format)*
2. **I don't understand how `stat` works?** *(It outputs a bunch of things, I just want the last modified date)*

Comment: Using dates in this fashion generally doesn't work.  You normally would want to embed the build SHA, or have a tag corresponding to the build, and log everything since that.

Comment: I suppose with Xcode I can store the git tag in my Info.plist like this: http://kylefuller.co.uk/posts/versioning-with-xcode-and-git/ and there must be a way to get the git log since a tag

Comment: Correct.  `git log ^$(TAG) $(SOME_BRANCH)`